# Visual C++ initliazing aggregates inline

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In g++ I could do this:

```
struct s
{
    int a, b;
};
void MyFunction(s) { }

int main()
{
    MyFunction((s) { 0, 0 });
    return 0;
}
```

In Visual Studio however, it doesn't work. is there any way to make it work or some alternative syntax without making a variable and initializing it (and without adding a constructor to the struct as it will make it non-aggregate and it wouldn't be able to initialize in aggregates)?

Answer (score 0):

My C is a bit rusty, but didn't you have to use `struct s` unless you `typedef` it? Something like this:

```
struct s
{
    int a, b;
};

void MyFunction(struct s) { }

int main()
{
    MyFunction((struct s) { 0, 0 });
    return 0;
}
```

or

```
typedef struct s
{
    int a, b;
} s_t;

void MyFunction(s_t) { }

int main()
{
    MyFunction((s_t) { 0, 0 });
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ok, silly me.. then it's the same problem as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054704/error-type-name-is-not-allowed-in-c so I guess there is no alternative to creating a variable.