# Workaround to get codes to work in MSVC++ 2010 due to "Type name is not allowed"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, unsigned, short, openni

I am trying to implement a finger detection, which link is given [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5505209/FingertipTuio3d.zip). Am I am going through the code in MSVC2010, it gives me error as shown in Figure as shown below. Could someone tell me why the following codes gives me error? Is this related to these following questions; [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9610747/which-c99-features-are-available-in-the-ms-visual-studio-compiler), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146381/visual-studio-support-for-new-c-c-standards/146419#146419), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054704/error-type-name-is-not-allowed-in-c)? Is there a possible workaround? I already included:

```
#include <cstdint> 
#include <stdint.h>
```

I also tried:

```
unsigned short depth = (unsigned short) (v[2] * 1000.0f); // hand depth
unsigned short near = (unsigned short) (depth - 100); // near clipping plane
unsigned short far = (unsigned short) (depth + 100); // far clipping plane
```

but did not work.

[image: Figure1. Error: Type name is not allowed]

Thanks,

ikel

Comment: don't include both `cstdint` and `stdint.h`. They are referring to the same thing, but `cstdint` is the proper one to use.

Comment: @nyarlathotep thanks for the input. I will remove `stdint.h`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that `near` and `far` are already `#define`d elsewhere as something else. This is typical if you have already included `windows.h`, which includes `windef.h` with following macros:

```
#define far
#define near
#if (!defined(_MAC)) && ((_MSC_VER >= 800) || defined(_STDCALL_SUPPORTED))
#define pascal __stdcall
#else
#define pascal
#endif
```

Try changing names into something like `plane_near` and `plane_far` and it will work.

Comment: Or (easier) just `#undef` them. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118774/is-there-a-clean-way-to-prevent-windows-h-from-creating-a-near-far-macro

Comment: I don't use `windows.h` nor `windef.h` I will give this one a go.

Comment: @Zdeslav Vojkovic, Thanks. It worked! I simply renamed both variables.

Comment: glad it worked. however, in your case, they are most likely included from some other location ('Go to declaration' will show you where). `undef` is safe if done inside the .cpp file (and safe in general on 32-bit platform - this is a compatibility 'feature').