# Weird errors by QT Creator on using near and far variable names

Tags: qt

I am using "Qt Creator 3.3.0 (opensource)" with "Qt 5.4.0 (MSVC 2010, 32 bit)"

In my camera class I'm getting weird errors I am not able solve it..

```
class camera
{
public:
    // for view matrix
    float theta, phi;
    float zoom;

    // for projection matrix
    float fovy;
    float width, height;
    float near, far;

    camera();
    camera(float inWidth, float inHeight );
    ~camera();

    mat4 perspective();
    mat4 view();
};
```

I'm getting error at line:

```
float near, far;
```

Errors are:

```
error: C2059: syntax error : ',' 
error: C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
error: C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
error: C2059: syntax error : ','
error: C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: What do you have above the class declaration? Are you compiling it as C++?

Comment: Yes it is in C++, and above it is,

#ifndef CAMERA_H


#define CAMERA_H

#include <linear_algebra/mat4.h>


class camera {
...
}

#endif // CAMERA_H

Comment: how does the source (.cpp) file look where you include your camera.h header? and what's in the mat4.h?

Comment: camera.cpp        

#include "camera.h"

#define PI 3.141


camera::camera() { .. }

....

Comment: It seems some qt creator issue instead of C++. but don't know hot to solve it.

Comment: The error is generated by the Visual C++ compiler you're using. Qt Creator is just your editor and tells the compiler to build your code.

Comment: Post the complete build log.

Comment: And the code snippets you provided are syntactically correct. So we're asking for the surroundings to check for any side effects. Is the error really from compiling camera.cpp? or maybe from another file where you include camera.h? Check the compiler output in detail.

Comment: Ok so here is my compiler output,

Comment: 18:41:26: Running steps for project 277...
18:41:26: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
18:41:28: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
 C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
 cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -GR -EHsc /Fddebug\277.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I"include" -I"..\scene_graph\src" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\5.4\msvc2012_opengl\include" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\5.4\msvc2012_opengl\include\QtWidgets" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\5.4\msvc2012_opengl\include\QtGui" -

Comment: I"C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\5.4\msvc2012_opengl\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"." -I"." -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\5.4\msvc2012_opengl\mkspecs\win32-msvc2012" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\Darshan\AppData\Local\Temp\mygl.obj.1112.32.jom
mygl.cpp
F:\Penn\CIS 277 Home Works\HW 3\scene_graph\src\camera.h(16) : error C2059: syntax error : ','
F:\Penn\CIS 277 Home Works\HW 3\scene_graph\src\camera.h(16) : error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
c1xx : fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
jom: F:\Penn\CIS 277 Home Works\HW 3\build-Qt_Widget_Example-

Comment: Desktop_Qt_5_4_0_MSVC2012_OpenGL_32bit-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\mygl.obj] Error 2
 cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -GR -EHsc /Fddebug\277.pdb -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I"include" -I"..\scene_graph\src" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\5.4\msvc2012_opengl\include" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\5.4\msvc2012_opengl\include\QtWidgets" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\5.4\msvc2012_opengl\include\QtGui" -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\5.4\msvc2012_opengl\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"." -I"." -I"C:\Qt\Qt5.4.0\5.4\msvc2012_opengl\mkspecs\win32-msvc2012" -Fodebug\

Comment: Omg, stop posting such comments. Use an edit option to your question... And read my answer, it will solve your issues.

Comment: It looks like `near` has been defined as a macro somewhere. If you change `near` to `nearr`, does the problem disappear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`near` and `far` are reserved keywords for memory model in C language. They are used in pointer declaration.

You need to use another names. You may view at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749904/difference-between-far-pointer-and-near-pointer-in-c?rq=1) for details.

Comment: Maybe that was true 20 years ago. Not in MSVC 2010.

Comment: @TonyK it is true for a lot of compilers. Especially for embedded devices. Microsoft compilers never follows standards, they have their own vision. I'm using MSVC 12 now, it's not completelly supports C++11, but has some features from C++17.

Comment: Sweet!! Thanks for saving my time.. :)
-Hare Krishna

Comment: The OP specified "Qt 5.4.0 (MSVC 2010, 32 bit)". That environment does not reserve the `near` and `far` keywords. The problem is somewhere else. But changing the names seems to fix it, so the problem is sovled :-)

Comment: @TonyK the problem is exactly in naming members.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But not because `near` and `far` are reserved keywords.

Comment: I use same class in Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012, and there it runs fine..

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12455122/428857) has the explanation: `near` and `far` are defined as (empty) macros in `windef.h` in MSVC 2010.

Comment: They are defined for backward compatibility with C code. I don't understand your downvote, but it's your decision.

Comment: @Thomas yes, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/11/17/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-preview.aspx

Comment: @SaZ thanks! thats why I didn't find it on google. :)

Comment: @Thomas you are welcome. But I'm not sure, about actual state of this table.

Comment: I downvoted because (i) your answer is wrong; and (ii) I posted four comments explaining why your answer is wrong, and you ignored them.

Comment: I ignored them, because answer solved this problem. So your downlvote is wrong. Problem was in `near` and `far` and it was necessary to research in OP evrironment, what is real reason.